# A user-friendly, fast way to delete the same field from several content types at once?

Tags: nodes

I have a Drupal 7.39 site with about 10 content types. All of these content types contains **2 fields** which I want to delete (It's a long story why).

Is there a way to delete both of these fields from all content types **at once**, instead of manually deleting each one of them from each content-type? Thanks,

Comment: To be honest, I don't quite believe that deleting fields (and thus losing data) should be either friendly or fast to do, especially in bulk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Field tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tools)

> A collection of useful UI tools for working with fields:
>
> - Overview of fields with links to edit single instances, and all    instances at once
> - Visual overview of relationships between entity types defined by    entityreference fields, taxonomy reference fields, and schema
>     properties, using GraphAPI
> - Clone any field instance to multiple entities and bundles
> - Clone all field instance of a bundle to multiple entities and bundles
> - Import and export fields
> - **Delete multiple instances of a field**
> - Apply a vocabulary to multiple entities and bundles at once (the same    way vocabularies were applied to content types on Drupal 6)
> - ... your idea here. Patches welcome!

Comment: I've installed the module - Can you please add a small update on where to go to delete the fields just to "Save time for all users to come"? Not critical but will be nice I guess.

Comment: T could see an option to clone or to delete the field from a single content type but not a "delete from all" button. Can you please elaborate on how to do the deletion of a field from all content types? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You can execute this code manually

```
field_delete_field('your_field_machine_name');
```

Comment: I'm a humble JS student and I've yet to acquire enough knowledge to know how to implement this. Where do I execute this code and how? (Maybe via Drush?), Can you please elaborate more via updating your answer?, Thanks,

Comment: The simpliest way to do it, is install module devel, open page devel/php and execute this code there.

Comment: DOMAIN/devel/php is url of page. On this page you can execute your PHP code. This page available only if you have enabled module devel.

Comment: @Eugene What if I want to delete a field of a certain content type? For example title field

Comment: @Umair, you can use function field_delete_instance, but I don't think that title field can be deleted. Actually, it's not classic field. It's system field.